# How to pass a select value to Angularjs modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, select

I'm sure this is very simple problem for you guys, but I'm stuck. I have a modal angularjs form and I'd like to execute a function when I press the "Assign" button. In the HTML template that creates the modal form, I have a select element and I want to pass a value. The code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#assignButton").on("click",function(event) {
    myValue = $("#sfc").selectmenu("value")
});
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="assignSFC.html">
    <div class="modal-header" style="fill: #f08a00">
        <h3>Assign SFC</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="sfc">Select a Service Chain</label>
            <select name="sfc" id="sfc">
              <option selected="selected" value="0">No Chain</option>
              <option value="1">Service Chain 1</option>
              <option value="2">Service Chain 2</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- <div class="alert alert-error" ng-model="error.msg">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
            <strong>Error!</strong>This is a fatal error. {{error.msg}}
        </div> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="assignButton" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok(value)">Assign</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

In the last button, if I put something like: ng-click="ok(2)", it will execute the assignSFC function perfectly. My problem is that I don't know how to pass these values (0,1,2) according to the selection in the form. 
Do you see anything idiotic?

THANKS AGAIN!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it in wrong way. Angularjs is two way binding, you are trying to mixup jQuery with angularjs. Angularjs has its own functions to achieve what you want. You haven't use controller and you are trying to use click button using ng-click.
Try below code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="assignSFC.html">
    <div ng-controller="TemplateController">
    <div class="modal-header" style="fill: #f08a00">
        <h3>Assign SFC</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="sfc">Select a Service Chain</label>
            <select name="sfc" id="sfc" ng-model="data.sfcSelection">
              <option selected="selected" value="0">No Chain</option>
              <option value="1">Service Chain 1</option>
              <option value="2">Service Chain 2</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- <div class="alert alert-error" ng-model="error.msg">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
            <strong>Error!</strong>This is a fatal error. {{error.msg}}
        </div> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="assignButton" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Assign</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

And here the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('TemplateController', ['$scope', TemplateController]);

function TemplateController($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.sfcSelection = [];
    $scope.ok = ok;

    function ok() {
        console.log($scope.selectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I was missing the ng-model directive! I didn't have time to learn properly AngularJS, that's why I got into this terrible design issues! Thanks!